# Can anyone identify the uniform my great uncle (child in the front of the photo) is wearing or any others in the pic?

Tags: world-war-one, royalty, belgium

[image]

Family photo taken on a family trip to Europe, possibly Belgium in 1918.

Comment: The clothing of the civilian couple suggests a date in the 1920s. Is that a possibility, based on the data you have? Nothing about the setting suggests Belgium to me. What countries other than Belgium may have been visited on this family trip through Europe? Why is this question tagged "royalty"? Are any of the persons in the picture known to be members of a royal house of Europe? If so, which person(s) and which royal house?

Comment: Family history suggests the young couple in civilian clothes could be Belgium royalty?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What confuses me is that the uniforms look British, not Belgian.

Comment: Weren't there probably British soldiers in Belgium in 1918 after the the Geramnas were driven out, and probably more than a dozen of them in the whole country?  I think that back in the 198s or so I once saw a group of sailors from some eastern Eruorpean country on shore leave in Philadelphia, PA.

Comment: The two adult civilians seem vaguely like [Elisabeth of Bavaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabeth_of_Bavaria,_Queen_of_the_Belgians) and her son [Prince Charles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Charles,_Count_of_Flanders).

Comment: Did your great uncle spend any time at  Wixenford School in Wokingham in England?

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I had thought one of the uniforms to be Belgium but still cannot match my uncle's or the others behind him.